# React native Detox e2e OTP Testing

Tags: react-native, detox

Ive implemented a OTP screen in my react-native project and I cant find a way to test it, I have the code for the OPT screen and I can either display the value and then tell detox to copy the text or tell it to use the state through context.

**State & context:**

but if I add `import {useContext} from 'react'` and then delcare my context `const appContext = useContext(APP_CONTEXT)` then use the `appContext.OTPCode` in my `.typeText` like so

`await element(by.id('appOTPCode')).typeText(appContext.OTPCode);`

it gives me a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error on `import {useContext} from 'react'`

is there a way to tell Detox e2e to accept such imports ?

**Display OPT code on screen and copy**

I cant find a way to tell detox to copy and paste the code if I display it as plain text on the screen via state.

is there a way to do something like this ?

If any of you have a solution or another way please be kind and share.

Thanks in andvance

Comment: Why want to test OTP scenario in STG/DEV build? Just ask the dev to disable them for testing purpose if this is not a core feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
  it('it should enter OTP', async () => {
    // get the OTP from the text field
    const otp = await element(by.id('otpText')).getAttributes();
    // enter the OTP into the OTP input field
    await element(by.id('otpText')).tap();
    await element(by.id('otpText')).typeText(otp.text);
  });
```